# How to add the values together in a key

Tags: python, dictionary

if I have a dictionary

```
example = {'cat' : 1, 'dog' : 2, 'cow' : 3, 'horse' : 4}
```

How would I add the values together?

I've tried

```
count = 0
for x in example:
    example[x] += count
    print example
```

But that just prints example three times. How do I do it so I get 10 as an answer?

Comment: the `example` declaration is invalid

Comment: ok my bad I meant dictionary haha that was just a slip up

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and [`dict.itervalues`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) ([`dict.values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) in Python 3.x):

```
>>> example = {'cat' : 1, 'dog' : 2, 'cow' : 3, 'horse' : 4}
>>> sum(example.itervalues())
10
>>>
```

Comment: `dict.values` is also present in Python 2

Comment: Yes, but it creates an unnecessary list.  `dict.itervalues` however returns an iterator like `dict.values` in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this:

```
example = {'cat' : 1, 'dog' : 2, 'cow' : 3, 'horse' : 4}
for x in example:
    count += example[x]
print count
```

Or:

```
example = {'cat' : 1, 'dog' : 2, 'cow' : 3, 'horse' : 4}
sum(example.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
example = {'cat' : 1, 'dog' : 2, 'cow' : 3, 'horse' : 4}
count = 0
for x in example:
    count += example[x]
print count
```

https://ideone.com/xHLkIg

Magnun Leno and iCodez's answers are more elegant (and pythonic) though.